# Could successful prayer tests demonstrate or increase the likelihood of god?

Tags: prayer

Using the statistical method to perform a controlled experiment often involves comparing the null hypothesis to what you would expect given a new theory.

Suppose one does a prayer test for the Abrahamic god on thousands of people with cancer. In one test group of 1000 people, prayers are made for those people. In another, prayers are not. In both test groups, standard medical protocols and treatments are still used to treat the cancer.

Suppose that every single person in the prayer test group survives. Suppose that about 30% of the non prayer test group survives. Assume, for the sake of argument, that the demographics of each test group are similar, and that treatments were done effectively and in the same way for each group. Assume this test was repeated in every country on earth with every single person in the prayer group always surviving and varying rates for the non prayer group.

Now, is this evidence of prayer working? Should this increase your credence in the Abrahamic god? Some might argue the former. Many, including many atheists or Bayesians, would argue the latter is true even if this is not demonstrative evidence.

What I’m having trouble with understanding is how this should make **any** difference in your credence of the Abrahamic god even though intuitively it feels like it should. Note that when I use the word should here, I mean whether it is **rational** to increase your credence, not whether it actually happens, which I suspect it would for almost all people. Now, in order for this god to have affected those people’s treatments, it must be apriori possible for this to occur. This would be possible only if this god exists.

The key word is apriori. If so, then the possibility of God’s actual existence must be independent of this prayer experiment. If so, then regardless of whatever your belief is of God’s **existence**, it seems that that credence should not change. After all, it is not as if it is scientifically **impossible** for all the people in the prayer group to be cured if there is no god, **even** if it is repeated hundreds of times. At best, it may be very **improbable**.

So, should your credence in god change from this prayer experiment, or not?

Comment: People are praying since 2.000 years: thus, the "experiment" has been done already.

Comment: The title says “successful” prayer test

Comment: Non-sequitur. To make statistics, prayers should be verified. Empirical validation is impossible, therefore scientific proof is impossible (unless thoughts are visible). Rational validation can only be subjective, therefore statistic proof is impossible (unless you pray and die several times and survive others). Therefore, non-sequitur.

Comment: Undestood... but it was implicit (sorry for this) that we have 2.000 years with millions of UNsuccessfull prayers.

Comment: How do you think empirical validation is done in science? Using statistics. I still agree with you but you’re arguably pointing out a flaw. If every single person in a test group was cured and in the alternative group wasn’t, and this was repeated, we would technically have “statistical proof.” Would it be enough? Arguably, and as per your point, no. Since we can’t observe how or what is actually causing that. And hence, we can’t rule out chance.